# Why am I allowed to assume x or y are equal to 0 in this Lagrange multipliers problem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I am working on a Lagrange multipliers problem where I have to find the extreme values of the function $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ along the constraint curve $g(x, y) = x^4 + y^4 = 1$.

Solving the Lagrange equations I get $\lambda = \frac{1}{2x^2}$ and $\lambda = \frac{1}{2y^2}$ i.e. $x = \pm y$. However, when plugging this result back into the constraint curve and solving for $g(x, y)$, I only get one extreme value, $\sqrt{2}$.

Solutions for this problem say that when you obtain the Lagrange equations you can also assume that $x$ or $y$ are equal to $0$. And when you plug these results back into the constraint curve, you get a minimum of $1$ when one of the variables equals $0$ and the other equals $\pm 1$.

What I am curious about is why exactly you are able to assume the $x$ or $y$ are equal to $0$ in this situation. My textbook says nothing about it and I can't find any examples of a problem where someone explains this. (The solution I found just assumed $x$ or $y$ equaled $0$ without any explanation.) My intuition is that it has something to do with the fact that $x$ and $y$ are in the denominator in this situation, but I'm not sure.

If someone could clear this up for me it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I only skimmed your post, but if $\lambda = \frac{1}{2x^2}$ then $\lambda$ is clearly not defined when $x\neq 0$. Are you sure, they're not looking at the two cases: firstly $x=0$, and secondly $x\neq 0$ where we in the last can define $\lambda$ by the previously mentioned expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't quite end up with

$$\lambda = \frac{1}{2x^2}$$

You end up with

$$2x = 4x^3\lambda$$

You can only divide by $4x^3$ if $x\neq 0$, otherwise the equality is true regardless of $\lambda$. So the possible solutions are

$$\lambda = \frac{1}{2x^2}\ \mathrm{or}\ x=0$$

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!